# swift os x array binary operator error compare with nil != if statement

Tags: arrays, macos, swift, if-statement

I have declared an array of an array of tuples:

```
 var graphDetailsArray: [Array<(graphType: String,  columnLabel: String, columnColor: NSColor, columnHeight: CGFloat, columnNumber: Int)>] = []
```

a little later on in the function I check this array for nil before activating some code:

```
    if graphDetailsArray != nil {  //some code here
```

This is throwing up an error at build time:

> Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to type Array<(graphType:
>   String,  columnLabel: String, columnColor: NSColor, columnHeight:
>   CGFloat, columnNumber: Int)> and nil.

I have a tried a range of different syntaxes and can not get this to work.

Any assistance would be appreciated.  How do I check for an empty array?

Is using "graphDetails.isEmpty" the same as checking for nil??

Comment: You can only check whether optionals are `nil`, since your array isn't optional you can't check whether it's nil. If you looking to see whether the array contains any values, use `isEmpty` as you suggested.

Comment: ABS - thanks for the clarification.  That also explains another error that I was getting.  I had assume that declaring the array as a var automatically set it to be an optional.  With a bit more reading I now realise that if I want it to be optional I need to specifically add '?' to the end of the array declaration  ...)>]? = [ ].  Hopefully I have understood that correctly.

Comment: That's indeed correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Your array is an array, not an optional array. While an optional array could be nil, a non-optional array in Swift can never, ever be nil. Therefore, it doesn't even support an if-statement that would compare it to nil.

Replace

```
graphDetailsArray != nil
```

with

```
true
```

or remove the if-statement completely.

isEmpty is something totally different. An array could have 0 elements, 1 element, 2 elements etc. isEmpty returns true if your array has 0 elements. Which is totally different from an array being nil.